# ABCMeta doesn't give me an exception

Tags: python

ABCMeta assures that the constructor gives an exception if you try to instantiate the abstract class, then why doesn't it give me an exception in the console if I run this code?

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class MyClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

x = MyClass()
```

Comment: Because it already implements all of the zero methods required.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i don't understand, what's the case in which it would give me the exception?

Comment: If you defined one or more `@abstractmethod`s that needed to be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta):

> A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are overridden

As you have no abstract methods or properties in `MyClass`, it can be instantiated.